# IBM MQ messages are transfering with delay from source to destination

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

IBM MQ messages are transfering with delay from source to destination .. from sourcce > channel > bridge(alias queue)> topic>bridge.remote.queue>remote channel ..  Please help how to trace and where the logs available to check message put time..

Comment: Consider using message route tracing: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/nl/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036600_.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are several diagnostic tools available.  One of the best is an exit that intercepts MQ API calls before and after and provides a human readable listing with `PUT`/`GET` times at system clock resolution.  It is provided as [SupportPac MA0W](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W).

A more quick and dirty diagnostic involves stopping the channels and seeing how quickly the message shows up int he XMitQ.  then start the channels one by one and follow the message through.  If the delay in question is on the order of several seconds or more, this is usually sufficient to find the app that is taking a long time to process the message.   (Because it is almost always application latency and not WebSphere MQ responsible for the delay.)